# Как исправить ошибку в генерации таблицы?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

У меня есть алгоритм для генерации таблицы из двух массивов.

data = [почта, кошка, собака]

words = [{почтальон, почтовый ящик, письмо}, {кошечка, котенок, кошак, котяра}, {пес, друг}]

Количество "подмассивов" в массиве words всегда равно количеству элементов в массиве data.

Массив data это заголовки столбцов, а "подмассивы" words должны быть столбцами.

Мой алгоритм генерации работает исправно, но "подмассивы" в моей имплементации получаются строками, а как я уже сказала, мне нужно чтобы это были столбцы.

```
<Paper style={{ maxWidth: 936, margin: "auto" }}>
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        {data.map((TableRow, i) => (
                            <TableCell key={i} align="center">
                                {TableRow.split("_").join(" ")}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {this.state.array.map((user, i) => (
                        <TableRow key={i}>
                            {Object.values(user).map((v, j) => (
                                <TableCell key={j} align="center">
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <AddIcon/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                    {v}
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <RemoveIcon/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                </TableCell>
                            ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell align="center">
                            <Button variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                style={{
                                    background:
                                        "linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)"
                                }}
                            >Обучить
                            </Button>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
```

Comment: не понимаю, почему отменили исправление с [{..., ..., ...}] на [[..., ..., ...]]?

Answer (score 0):

1) Находите самый длинный подмассив (до return в render) - это будет количество строк вашей таблицы

```
let maxLength = 0;
const words = [['почтальон', 'почтовый ящик', 'письмо'], ['кошечка', 'котенок', 'кошак', 'котяра'], ['пес', 'друг']];
words.map(item => {
     if (item.length > maxLength) maxLength = item.length
})
```

2) Далее внутри TableBody:

```
<TableBody>
{
     // это массив для строк
     [...Array(maxLength)].map((item, i) => {
           // это массив для столбцов
           return (
              <TableRow>
                   {
                        [...Array(data.length)].map((element, j) => {
                            return (
                                 <TableCell>
                                     {
                                         words[j][i] ? words[j][i] : null
                                     }
                                 </TableCell>
                            )
                        }) 
                   }
             </TableRow>
     })
 }
 </TableBody>
```